# spatial data clustering with sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, spatial

I have arrays of latitude and longitude data points which I want to do hierachical clustering. Here is my code:

```
position = zip(longitude, latitude)
X = np.asarray(position) 

knn_graph = kneighbors_graph(X, 30, include_self=False, metric= haversine)

for connectivity in (None, knn_graph):
    for n_clusters in(5,8,10,15,20):
        plt.figure(figsize=(4, 5))
        cnt = 0 
        for index, linkage in enumerate(('average', 'complete', 'ward')):
                model = AgglomerativeClustering(linkage = linkage,
                                                connectivity = connectivity,
                                                n_clusters = n_clusters)
                model.fit(X)
                plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=model.labels_,
                            cmap=plt.cm.spectral)
                plt.title('linkage=%s  (ncluster) %s)' % (linkage, n_clusters),
                                      fontdict=dict(verticalalignment='top'))
                plt.axis([37.1, 37.9, -122.6, -121.6])
  plt.show()
```

the problem is for `kneighbors_graph` there is a parameter called `metric` which is how we defined the destination,http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.kneighbors_graph.html I want to define my own(real distance regard to the logitude and latitude and earth radius). Let seems I could not plug in my own function, any ideas?

Comment: And `affinity="haversine"` does not work? Then use a precomputed distance matrix, or ELKI.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse, hmmm, it works now, I just forget the " "(Stupid). By the way, in the knn_graph the distance is defined by "haversine", when doing  the agglomerative clustering, will the function we try to minimize, which is  the "average, complete, ward distance", this distance is also the haversine distance or not?

Comment: You need to pass the `affinity` to the clusteeing. See the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

- the distance function expects a string usually (e.g. `"haversine"`)
- you have *two* locations where you use a distance, then knn graph *and* as affinity for the clustering.
- hierarchical clustering has two types of distances, and thus two distance parameters. One is the distance of objects (e.g. haversine), the other is the distance of clusters, which is usually derived from that other disance by aggregation (e.g. maximum, minimum). Both are often called "distance". In sklearn, the first is called `affinity`.